Neovim Typescript type hints are out of control
First, I'm only a few weeks new to Vim and Neovim.
I recently updated via LazyVim and added the Typescript language via :LazyExtras because I have used TS in the past and plan on in the future, but now, my code is just flooded with crap.


Function parameter type hints are soooo long I can't even see the end of the lines
The "info panel" showing up as I type things like console.log() wasn't there before and although informative, I'd like to know how to configure it

Where do I turn off the Typescript type definition hints (I'm working in a .js file)?
What is providing the type suggestions / autocomplete / whatever?
Also, this is all I have installed via :LazyExtras:


I think this is related to inlay_hints. Still researching but have to stop soon.

I don't know what the info panel is from, not that I dislike it, but I found that via LazyVim, I can simply <leader>+u+h to turn off "inlay hints."
Lifesaver.
